# How to find the current template id and name in the usercontrol

Tags: umbraco

To look for current node we use ,

```
Node currentNode = Node.GetCurrent();

string myValue = currentNode.GetProperty("productDetails").Value;

lblProductDetails.Text = myValue;
```

but i have a got a scenario where i have to pass the property depending on the templates, i have got two templates which are using different document types, so if template1 get (Template1property1,......) similarly if Template2 get (Template2property1,......).

Is it possible to acheive something like this or is there a better way of working out this in a single user control,

Any assistance or help will be appreciated ,

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Indeed you can, there are in fact many ways but I'll show the *"I'm using a .Net User Control behind my macro"* route. I'm going to make a few assumptions in order to demonstrate how to do it, since they're not outlined in your question.

### Assumptions

```
Name (Alias) [Type]

Product (product) [Document Type]
  - Product Details (productDetails) [Property]
  - Product Template (productTemplate) [Default Template]

Event (event) [Document Type]
  - Event Details (eventDetails) [Property]
  - Event Template (eventTemplate) [Default Template]
```

### How To

What were going to do is create a .Net property on the User Control and then let the template decide which Umbraco property name to look for. This way means you don't have to depend on a bunch of if statements.

1 . Code your user control (in Visual Studio) and make sure you have a property defined in the code, like the following

```c
    private string _detailsProperty;
    public string DetailsProperty
    {
        set { this._detailsProperty = value; }
    }
```

2 . Upload your user control to the `/usercontrols/` folder in the web root, and your DLL (if compiled) to the `/bin/` folder.

3 . Create the macro (in Umbraco) and assign to your user control. Let's name the macro `MyAbstractControl` and then assign your .Net User Control to it from the drop down. Then click Save (Important!).

4 . If you clicked Save in the step above, a Browse Properties button should appear. Click on that and you'll see your property from the User Control. Ensure the box is checked and then click on the Save Properties button. To check if it's done, reload the Macro and go to the Properties tab and see your User Control's Property added to the list.

5 . Add something like the following code to your templates to look for different Umbraco property aliases.

```html
    <!-- put in template : productTemplate -->
    <umbraco:Macro Alias="MyAbstractControl" DetailsProperty="productDetails" runat="server">

    <!-- put in template : eventTemplate -->
    <umbraco:Macro Alias="MyAbstractControl" DetailsProperty="eventDetails" runat="server">
```

6 . You can then make a minor update to the code in your question to something like the following in order for it to behave as desired

```c
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this._detailsProperty))
    {
        Node currentNode = Node.GetCurrent();
        string myValue = currentNode.GetProperty(this._detailsProperty).Value;
        lblProductDetails.Text = myValue;
    }
```

Hope that helps.